# Determine the number of chunks in the selection from an hdf5 file

Tags: python, hdf5, chunks, hdfstore

When selecting from an `hdf5` file in chunks, I would like to know how many chunks there are in the resulting selection.

Number of rows in the input data `nrows` can be up to 100mln, `chunksize` is 100k, but for most selections the number of rows in a chunk `nrows_chunk` is smaller, so for different `where` I can have selections with one or many chunks. Before doing operations with chunks and at the time of calling `iteratorGenerator()` I would like to know how many chunks there will be. Intuitively, I want something like `len(list(enumerate(iteratorGenerator())))` in my syntax, but this would give length=1 (I suppose because only one chunk at a time is considered by `iteratorGenerator()`).

I suspected there is no solution to this issue as the whole idea of using generator is not to perform all selections at once but do it chunk by chunk. But actually, when I run the `for` loop below, the very first iteration takes really long, but the following iterations take just a seconds, which suggests that on the first iteration most of the data about chunks is collected. This is puzzling to me and I would appreciate any explanation on how selection by chunks works.

```
iteratorGenerator = lambda: inputStore.select(
                groupInInputStore,
                where=where,
                columns=columns,
                iterator=True,
                chunksize=args.chunksize
            )

nrows = inputStore.get_storer(groupInInputStore).nrows

# if there is more than one chunk in the selection:
for i, chunk in enumerate(iteratorGenerator()):
    # check the size of a chunk 
    nrows_chunk = len(chunk)
    # do stuff with chunks, mainly groupby operations

# if there is only one chunk do other stuff
```

Moreover, I am not sure what the `chunksize` in `HDFStore.select` refers to. From my experience, it is a maximal size of the selected chunk after applying `where` condition. On the other hand, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.HDFStore.select.html defines *chunksize: nrows to include in iteration*, which to me sounds like the number of rows to read from. Which is correct?

Comment: It doesn't quite answer your question, but for others who end up here:

For finding the number of chunks in a dataset, you can use [`get_num_chunks()`](https://api.h5py.org/h5d.html?highlight=chunk#h5py.h5d.DatasetID.get_num_chunks) from the low-level API. 

This function operates on the dataset id:
`hdf5_file[<dset_name>].id.get_num_chunks()`